# Why ECB does not jump to tags when hitting Return?

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

I have emacs 23.1 on Linux, CEDET 1.0.1, ECB snapshot. When opening a Python code file, I tried to move cursor on a function tag in the ECB methods buffer, and hit Return to jump to the function definition. But nothing happens except the cursor moves back to the editing window, and stays on the original position. Shift+LeftMouseButton click does not work either. However, right clicking on the function tag to pop up the shortcut menu, and selecting any "jump to" command DOES work, but it is very inconvenient to use mouse. Does anybody has the same problem? Do I need to customize my emacs init file for jump-by-hitting-Return? Help is much appreciated.

**Solved:**
After removing '(ecb-maximize-ecb-window-after-selection t) from custom-set-variables, everything get back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I have emacs 24.091, ECB 2.40 and hitting Ret on methods - does bring point to the appropriate method in the edit window.